# FPDF: How to use Colon symbol ₡

Tags: php, fpdf

How can I show ₡ symbol on a PDF?

I tried to use `html_entity_decode('&#8353;')` but it did not work. I thought of using ASCII Code but there's no ASCII Code for that symbol.

Comment: You could try using utf8_encode

Comment: It does not work. I tried like this: `utf8_encode('&#8353;')`

Comment: What type of encoding is the final pdf on?

Comment: I guess it's the standard encoding

Comment: You could probably try a different encoding of the same symbol from here : 
https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20a1/index.htm

Comment: @BoianIvanov What do you think `utf8_encode` does? There are much better functions to use instead e.g. [`iconv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

Comment: FPDF doesn't support UTF out-of-the-box as far as I'm aware. Take a look [here](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php).

Comment: @msg I changed to tFPDF but still nothing works

Comment: Did you set an unicode font as the example states? Can you post some code?